# Cast object to non explicit implemented interface

Tags: c#, inheritance

It's somehow possible to cast an object to an interface which it doesnt inherit directly? In my sample code below, is there any way to convert an All instance to a Single one?

```
public interface  IA
{
    void A();
}

public interface IB
{
    void B();
}

public interface IC : IA, IB
{
}

public class All : IA, IB
{
    public void A()
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("ALL A");
    }

    public void B()
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("ALL B");
    }
}

public class Single : IC
{
    public void A()
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("SINGLE A");
    }

    public void B()
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("SINGLE B");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        All all = new All();
        Single single = (Single)(all as IC); // Always null
        single?.A();
    }
}
```

Comment: The class `All` does not actually implement `IC` at all ("indirect inheritance" is something else). It sounds like you're after duck-typing, which C# does not support (`dynamic` doesn't count).

Comment: @Dai No, it doesn't explicitly, but in fact they share the same signature. Just wondering if this could be done somehow, but guessing it can't be ;-)

Comment: The point is that in `IC` you could have implemented/added many new functions. What would be behavior of `single` in those scenarios after casting `all` to `IC` type. Hence its not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use [the Adapter Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

```
class AllIC : IC {
    private readonly All all;
    public AllIC(All all) {
        if( all == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(all));
        this.all = all;
    }

    public void A() => this.all.A();
    public void B() => this.all.B();
}

static void Main()
{
    All all = new All();
    IC ic = new AllIC( all ); // Observe that `ic` is typed as interface `IC` instead of the concrete type `Single`.
    ic.A();
}
```

Note that unlike `interfaces` you cannot coerce one concrete type to another (in this case, your casting to `Single`), you must change your local variable type from a concrete type (`Single`) to an interface (`IC`).

Comment: Thanks. It' s a possible solution

Comment: You don't need `as IC` for `AllIC` instance. And you will get a runtime exception on on cast to `(Single)` because `AllIC` is not a `Single`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I overlooked that `Single` class. I've corrected my answer.